# Know dhcp server of lan

Tags: dhcp

It's possible show ip of the server that give me ip and other DHCP option?

Basically i would like to understand which is the dhcp server of the lan i am connected to.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to find the lease file of your DHCP client. It might be in directory `/var/lib/NetworkManager/` if you are using NetworkManager, or in a DHCP-client-specific directory. For example, if you're using `dhclient` as your DHCP client, you might find it as `/var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.<network interface name>.leases`.

For example, on my headless Debian 10 system with no NetworkManager and using `dhclient`, the network interface is `enp1s0f1` and the lease file is `/var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.enp1s0f1.leases`. It contains a number of lease definitions like this:

```
lease {
  interface "enp1s0f1";
  fixed-address 192.0.2.4;
  option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
  option routers 192.0.2.1;
  option dhcp-lease-time 18000;
  option dhcp-message-type 5;
  option domain-name-servers 192.0.2.53,192.0.2.54;
  option dhcp-server-identifier 198.51.100.67;
  option domain-name "isp.example.com";
  renew 4 2021/08/05 07:42:46;
  rebind 4 2021/08/05 09:52:18;
  expire 4 2021/08/05 10:29:48;
}
```

Here, the `option dhcp-server-identifier` line will identify the DHCP server that gave you the IP address and the other configuration information described in the lease. Note that the DHCP server might be in a completely different network segment; in that case, there will be a DHCP helper somewhere on the local network that will listen for DHCP request broadcasts, forward them to the actual DHCP server, and broadcast any returned answers back to the local network segment when needed (i.e. while the client does not have its own IP address yet).

My laptop uses NetworkManager, so its lease file can be found at `/var/lib/NetworkManager/dhclient-<long-uuid-string>-<interface name>.lease`, but the contents of the lease file are similar. But with NetworkManager, you can also use a command like `nmcli c` to list your NetworkManager connection names, then `nmcli c show <connection name>` to get more information. On an active connection that uses DHCP, this information should include a line like:

```
DHCP4.OPTION[n]:      dhcp_server_identifier = 192.51.100.67
```

(where `n` is some number)

Again, the `dhcp_server_identifier` will tell you the IP address of the DHCP server that gave an IP address to this connection.

Other DHCP clients might have different file formats, or even a different way of storing the lease information altogether.

Comment: Thanks!!! I use NetworkManager but in the folder /var/lib/NetworkManager/ there aren't dhclient files...i think that i've to enable some features in Network Manager to make the file dhclient-<long-uuid-string>-<interface name>.lease
There are only files as internal-ae5cf54d-bef9-40c1-9bf3-57555528dffb-<mynet>.lease

Comment: However...with command that you suggested:
nmcli conn show  <connection name> | grep dhcp_server
i can find ip!!
THANKS!!

Comment: "internal" instead of "dhclient" suggests your distribution is using NetworkManager's internal DHCP client instead of `dhclient` like mine. That would be the "other DHCP clients" case of my answer, but you might want to see if your `internal-ae5cf54d-bef9-40c1-9bf3-57555528dffb-<mynet>.lease` contains the lease information in a readable form. That's a good example of minor differences that exist between Linux distributions, and also why you should have mentioned the name of the distribution you're asking about.

Comment: thanks! but I had already looked in internal-xxx-mynetcat.lease but there is onlu my IDADRESS...
i'va also do a grep -r dhcp-server-identifier /var/lib/NetworkManager/ but not information about server
However,as in precedent message, qith command nmcli show etc... i find dhcp server address
thanks for all ;-)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following commands to know the dhcp server which issued ip address.

```
-> % ip r
default via 192.168.0.1 dev eno1 proto dhcp src 192.168.0.100 metric 100 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown 
192.168.0.0/24 dev eno1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.100 
192.168.0.1 dev eno1 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.0.100 metric 100 
a
-> % route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eno1
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eno1
192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    100    0        0 eno1
```

in the above 192.168.0.1 is the gateway. 192.168.0.100 is the ip address of current machine.

Comment: thanks! but for me, from user or root don't show dhcp server!?!?
# ip route 
default via 10.1.1.1 dev enp0s20f0u6u2 proto dhcp metric 100 
10.1.0.0/22 dev enp0s20f0u6u2 proto kernel scope link src 10.1.2.97 metric 100 

# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.1.1.1        0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp0s20f0u6u2
10.1.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.252.0   U     100    0        0 enp0s20f0u6u2

Comment: The default gateway is not always the DHCP server. In home router setups it might often be that, but in enterprise network setups that isn't usually true.